# sklearn and Tensorflow with dual CPU machine

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, cpu

I am thinking about building a dual-CPU machine for machine learning. I already have a fast GPU in my current rig but I am limited to 32GB of DDR3, I have an i7-4790k and I am planning to upgrade to dual E5 2683 v3's.

I need CPU computing power for sklearn and grid search. Does Sklearn work on 2 cpu's the same it does on 1? Will it use all the cores on both CPU's when n_jobs=-1?

Will tensorflow only work on the one CPU when training on my GPU? If I just copy and pasted the MNIST for experts tutorial on the TF website would it use both CPU's and my GPU without specifying the devices?

I choose not to put this on the superuser forum because it is more about the software than the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read even if you add an instruction like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    ...
```

It treats it as a recommendation and might use the GPU when it sees fit.
I guess it might use the other CPU

Comment: I think that will train on only the cpu0
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html

Comment: I remember to have read somewhere that the device assignment is not really strict, I can't find it now